# Filtrar rango de fechas y enviar datos por medio de lista desplegable

Tags: php, sql, lista

Tengo el siguiente codigo `PHP` y `HTML` quiero filtrar por fechas primero y luego enviar datos por medio de una lista desplegable. pero cuando lo ejecuto me muestra el siguiente error:

> syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL) in C:\AppServ\www\centrales\index.php on line 21 la linea 21 es esta:

```
if(isset($desde))==false)
    {$desde == $hasta;}
```

Alguna solución o mejora agradecere comentarios.

```
<html>
<section

<table border="3" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="date" id="bd-desde"/></td>
        <td>Hasta&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="date" id="bd-hasta"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</section>

<?php 
$desde = $_POST['desde'];
$hasta = $_POST['hasta'];


if(isset($desde))==false){$desde = $hasta;}
        if(isset($hasta)==false){
        $hasta = $desde;
    if(isset($_POST['filtro'],$_POST['desde'],$_POST['hasta'])){
    switch($_POST['filtro']){
        case "Nimajuyu":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (02) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "El Carmen 2":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (04) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Monte Verde 5":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (05) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Lourdes EIN":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (08) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Guarda Transito":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (11) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Guarda Viejo 5":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (12) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Centro Transito EIN":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (15) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Tivoli":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (205) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Villa de Guadalupe 3":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (207) 
                    order by archivo_dcms asc;";
            break;
        case "Aristos":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (208) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Chimaltenango":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (302) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Retalhuleu":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (304) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
        case "Zacapa":
            $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms) in(19) AND central in (307) 
                    order by central,correlativo_dcms, archivo_dcms;";
            break;
    }
}else{
    $sql = "select * from tarificado.rep_con where extract(week from fecha_dcms)";
}
?>
```

Comment: sobra un = en la segunda parte.. la asignacion es solo con un simbolo =

Comment: Muchas gracias gbianchi lo he colocado ahora me aparece el siguiente error:SQL error: ERROR: el argumento de WHERE debe ser de tipo boolean, no tipo double precision; Error while executing the query, SQL state 42804 in SQLExecDirect in                                                     la linea de php es la siguiente:   $sql = odbc_exec($cid,$sql); muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ni idea, no estas diciendo donde se produce ese error. Igual despues de ver las querys, esta mal como lo hace. La query deberia ser una sola, y pasarle los valores necesarios como parametros. no tiene sentido escribirla todas las veces adentro de un case eterno.